# Summoning and Displaying a text file, inside a menu function

Tags: c++, function, menu, switch-statement, text-files

I'm quite new to C++ and my assignment is pretty tough. I must create a menu (in which I'm struggling quite badly), not only that but I should also read and display a textfile. So far, the only method I used only displays the first lines of the text file. Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

The break function when added to the first case also makes the loop an infinite wall of texts! I dont know what to do..

```
    // Assignment 1.cpp : Tally Ho Generator

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int runMenu;

int main()
{
    int menuInput;
    bool menu = true;
    ifstream inFile;
    string ABOUT;

    // Menu Interface
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << "   The Tally Ho Probability Generator (MCD4720_Assignment 1)\n";
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << " [1] End Testing the Program\n";
    cout << " [2] Display About Information\n";
    cout << " [3] Read and store data from files\n";
    cout << " [4] Generate a Dice Tally Table\n";
    cout << " [5] Save Tally Statistics to a file\n";
    cout << " [6] Load Tally Statistics from a file\n";
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << "Which Option would you like (1-6)\n";
    cin >> runMenu;


    // Menu Input Function
    while (menu != false) {
        switch (runMenu)
        {
        case 1:
        {

            inFile.open("C:\\Users\\William\\Documents\\MCD Assignment 4720 1\\TallyAbout.txt");
            while (getline(inFile, ABOUT)) {
                cout << ABOUT << endl;
                inFile.close();

            }
            break;
        }
        

        case 2:
        {}
        case 3:
        {}
        case 4:
        {}
        case 5:
        {}
        case 6:
        {}

        default: {
            cout << " Input unrecognized, please choose again \n";
            cin >> runMenu;
            break;
        }
        }
        }


        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();

        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, the only method I used only displays the first lines of the text file

That is because you close the file after reading the first line:

> ```
>         while (getline(inFile, ABOUT)) {
>             cout << ABOUT << endl;
>             inFile.close();                // <------ here !!
>
>         }
> ```

You do not need to close the file explicitly. The file is closed in the destructor of `inFile`.

> The break function when added to the first case also makes the loop an infinite wall of texts! I dont know what to do..

That is because `break` breaks out of the switch. No other case will be handled. In particular, your `default` case where you ask for user input will not be executed. Actually you never modify the value of `menu` and `while(menu != false)` is an infinite loop. Move the part that has to be done for any case out of the switch:

```
while (menu != false) {
    switch (runMenu)
    {
        case 1:
        {

            inFile.open("C:\\Users\\William\\Documents\\MCD Assignment 4720 1\\TallyAbout.txt");
            while (getline(inFile, ABOUT)) {
                cout << ABOUT << endl;
                inFile.close();

            }
            break;
        }
        
        //...
        default: {
            cout << " Input unrecognized, please choose again \n";      
            break;
        }
    }
  
    cin >> runMenu;
    // put logic here, for example:
    menu = (runMenu == 1);
}
```

You should modify the output accordingly. Currently it says " Input unrecognized, please choose again ", but if I understand correctly, the user has to choose to continue or not on every iteration. Also using one and not two variables for `menu` and `runMenu` would be less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you! So that means in each case, I must comprehensively also code what will happen next after the display has been chosen right?

Comment: If I understand the menu correctly you can choose after every input what to do next except for etnering "1" which will end the program. So the loading you implemented should go to case '2' for loading the about file and in case '1' you should set `menu = false`. This will end the while loop and your program should end

Comment: @MatzZze not sure if I understand your comment. In the example I posted `1` is the only case that is present, so `runMenu==1` is an ok condition to continue or not. To stop the loop the user only has to enter any number other than 1

Comment: You print the following line at the start :`cout << " [1] End Testing the Program\n";`
That means by entering 1 in the menu the program should end.
Entering `2` should print the about info printed here: `cout << " [2] Display About Information\n";`

Comment: @MatzZze seems to be a misunderstanding. I am not printing that at the start. I suppose you want to direct your comments to OP instead

Comment: @MatzZze fwiw, I think what OP implemented as `1` should actually be `[6] Load Tally Statistics from a file` ... no, rather `[2] Display About Information`

Comment: @idclev463035818 yeah sorry my bad. Thought comment was from OP... I think it would be better if your line `menu = (runMenu == 1);` would be `menu = !(runMenu == 1);` so that the menu will always be available unless the user enters a `1` to end the program and using `case '1': break;` to do nothing

Comment: Thanks Again Matt. I just realized that 1 is to End the Program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case 1:
{
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\William\\Documents\\MCD Assignment 4720 1\\TallyAbout.txt");
    while (getline(inFile, ABOUT)) {
        cout << ABOUT << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    break;
}
```

You are closing the file after you read the first line
The difference now is that you close the file after you read all lines

Comment: Thank you! This fixed everything. Thanks Again